# How to disable location of any website (automated chrome) using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, location

I'm using selenium - Webdriver , Chromedriver, python. One of my tests needs to turn off (disable) the location service on Chrome so as to carry on the further code.

I notice that by default, the location service is turned on Chromedriver.

Is their a way to disable location service on chromedriver using python code?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Use the ChromeOptions class, in the following way:

```
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
 jsonObject.put("profile.default_content_settings.geolocation", 2);

 options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", jsonObject);
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

You can see it as an answer for an issue [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=138)