# How to disable location of every website using selenium and powershell?

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to turn off location in Chrome when using selenium and powershell but nothing seems to work. I've tried this:

```
$Chrome = New-Object -TypeName "OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions"
$Chrome.AddArguments('disable-blink-features')
$Chrome.AddArguments('disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
$Chrome.AddArguments('--disable-geolocation')
$Chrome.AddArguments('--disable-location')
$Chrome.AddArguments('mute-audio')
$Chrome.AddArguments('--disable-features=UseMediaEngagementBypass')
$Chrome.AddArguments('start-maximized')

$Chrome.AddUserProfilePreference("webrtc.ip_handling_policy", "disable_non_proxied_udp")
$Chrome.AddUserProfilePreference("webrtc.multiple_routes_enabled", $false)
$Chrome.AddUserProfilePreference("webrtc.nonproxied_udp_enabled", $false)

$prefs = @{ "profile.default_content_settings.geolocation" = 2 }
$experimentalOptions = @{ "prefs" = $prefs }
$jsonOptions = $experimentalOptions | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
$Chrome.AddAdditionalCapability("goog:chromeOptions", $jsonOptions)

$Chrome.BinaryLocation = $customChromePath
$Driver = New-Object -TypeName "OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver($Chrome)" -ArgumentList $Chrome
```

This gives me error:

Exception calling "AddAdditionalCapability" with "2" argument(s): "There is already an option for the goog:chromeOptions capability. Please use the  instead.
Parameter name: capabilityName

Not sure what else to try.

Comment: Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72263607/how-to-disable-location-of-any-website-automated-chrome-using-selenium)

Comment: @yusuf i've tried that, see my code